# Client socket doesn't take any input from cmd

Tags: java, sockets, io

I create a program where server sends a list of files to client which the client can then request to check the contents. It sends the list of files properly but then the client doesn't take any input from console.
This is the server program

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPServer{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4888);
    while(true){
    Socket client = server.accept();
    System.out.println(client);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    File path = new File("C://testjava");
    String[] files = path.list();
    String send = "";
    for(String file:files){
        send = send + file + "\n";
    }
    out.writeBytes(send);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream    ()));
    String search_file = in.readLine();
    String searching = "";
    for(String file:files){
        if (file.equals(search_file)){
        searching = search_file;
        }
    }
if(searching.equals("")){
        out.writeBytes("Requested file does not exist");
        client.close();
    }
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader(searching));
    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        out.writeBytes(file.nextLine());
    }
    client.close();
    }
    }
}
```

This is the client program

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPClient{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost",4888);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String  display = ""; 
        while ((display = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(display);
        }
        System.out.println("\nChoose a file");
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ask_file = src.nextLine();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(ask_file);
        display = ""; 
        while ((display = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(display);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the client isn't accepting any input?
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the client, `in.readLine()` blocks until the Socket is closed.

Since you clearly don't want to close the socket yet, you could have the server send a special message to match for in the loop.  When matched, break out of the loop.

Also, readLine/nextLine like methods gobble up newlines, so you need to add some like @EJP said.  I edited your coded below.  I tested it and it seems to be working now.

TCPServer

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPServer{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4888);
    while(true){
    Socket client = server.accept();
    System.out.println(client);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    File path = new File("C://Users/Brian/Desktop");
    String[] files = path.list();
    String send = "";
    for(String file:files){
        send = send + file + "\n";
    }
    send = send + "END\n"; // ADD SOMETHING LIKE THIS ------------------------------>
    out.writeBytes(send);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream    ()));
    String search_file = in.readLine();
    String searching = "";
    for(String file:files){
        if (file.equals(search_file)){
        searching = search_file;
        }
    }
if(searching.equals("")){
        out.writeBytes("Requested file does not exist");
        client.close();
    }
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader(searching));
    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        out.writeBytes(file.nextLine() + "\n"); // ADD A NEWLINE HERE ------------------>
    }
    client.close();
    }
    }
}
```

TCPClient

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPClient{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost",4888);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String  display = ""; 
        // ADD A TEST FOR "END" HERE --------------------------------------------->
        while ((display = in.readLine()) != null && !display.equals("END")) {
            System.out.println(display);
        }
        System.out.println("\nChoose a file");
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ask_file = src.nextLine() + "\n"; // ADD A NEWLINE HERE ----------->
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(ask_file);
        display = ""; 
        while ((display = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(display);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. You need to add a `\n` to the strings you're writing with `writeBytes()`. Otherwise `readLine()` blocks forever waiting for a line terminator that never arrives.